# jquery css background image slideshow with transtion effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I need to add some nice transition fade effect to the change of the following simple sideshow:

```js
    var images = [
 "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w",
      "http://cimages.prvd.com/is/image/ProvideCommerce/PF_15_R105_MINIMAL_VA0211_W1_SQ?$PFCProductImage$",
      "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--8a-AXhau--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/zec3un8rzcmblrdlyswb.jpg",
      "http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/purplecrocus.jpg",
      "http://www.ninthstreetflowers.com/smp/Smp1/images/flower4.jpg",
      "http://magic-spells-and-potions.com/images/flower-language-vertical.png",
    ];

    var i = 0;
    var div;
    $(function() {

      div = $('.header_summer');
      console.log("loaded");
      setTimeout(changeBack, 1000);
    });

    function changeBack() {
      i = ++i % images.length;
      if (i > images.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
      console.log('url("' + images[i] + '");');

      // div.css('background-image', "url('" + images[i] + "')");

      // preload image check

//
    $('<img/>').attr('src', images[i]).load(function() 
    {
     $(this).remove();
     $('.header_summer').css('background', 'url("' + images[i] +'") no-repeat 0px 0px');
  });
  
  //
      setTimeout(changeBack, 5000);
    }
```

```css
.header_summer  {
 background: url('../tpl/mblmhv1/images/summer_cover1.jpg') no-repeat 0px 0px;
 
 background-size: cover;
 min-height:920px; /* 800px; */
 
 
 
 /* TRANSISITION - not qorking here
 transition(background-image 0.5s ease-in-out);
 
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <div class='header_summer'></div>
```

I have tried appending .fadeIn() to the jquery line that changes the image, and transition effects in the CSS - what am I missing?

Comment: I put two different approaches to this in a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299477/jquery-background-image-fading-function-causes-high-cpu-usage-on-chrome-and-oper/  If you need help implementing with your specifics let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.header_summer {
    background: url('../tpl/mblmhv1/images/summer_cover1.jpg') no-repeat 0px 0px;

    background-size: cover;
    min-height:920px; /* 800px; */
    transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with just the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) property defined on your CSS class as any changes to the element should trigger the transition (i.e. when you update the `background`, you should see the transition):

```
.header_summer {
  background: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w') no-repeat 0px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 920px;
  /* Transitions and their cross-browser friends */
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

The syntax generally uses the form `<property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>`, so your current transition would be looking for the `opacity` property to change, which it doesn't seem to be.

You should consider using `background` instead :

```
transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
```

**Example**

[image]

```css
.header_summer {
  background: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w') no-repeat 0px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 920px;

  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Flowers and stuff...</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Your element to switch through -->
  <div class='header_summer'></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Define your images
    var images = [
 "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w",
      "http://cimages.prvd.com/is/image/ProvideCommerce/PF_15_R105_MINIMAL_VA0211_W1_SQ?$PFCProductImage$",
      "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--8a-AXhau--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/zec3un8rzcmblrdlyswb.jpg",
      "http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/purplecrocus.jpg",
      "http://www.ninthstreetflowers.com/smp/Smp1/images/flower4.jpg",
      "http://magic-spells-and-potions.com/images/flower-language-vertical.png",
    ];
     // Define your variables
    var i = 0;
    var div;
    $(function() {
      // Set up your div
      div = $('.header_summer');
      console.log("loaded");
      setTimeout(changeBack, 1000);
    });

    function changeBack() {
      i = ++i % images.length;
      if (i > images.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
      console.log('url("' + images[i] + '");');
      div.css('background-image', "url('" + images[i] + "')");
      setTimeout(changeBack, 5000);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rion, are you seeing a transition work on your example? I don't, I just see an immediate change.

Comment: What browser are you using? It's appearing as expected for me.

Comment: Firefox. get the same in MS edge (IE wtf) I can just about make out that you have a transition from your attached GIF, but the snippet preview just shows immediate change with no fade transition. I'm using an Intel i7 so i don't think its my CPU!

Comment: Does the example work if you were to use `background` within the transition declaring like the second example prior to the .gif

Comment: Firefox, does the same in MS Edge (IE). Im running an Intel i7 so I don't think its my CPU - just tried a restart too - still the same. Very strange.

Comment: have tried now with smaller images, using transition: 1s ease-in-out; transition: background 1s ease-in-out; transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;.... still no transition effect.

Comment: gone cross eyed now. will check in the morning!